# flutter type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'Int64?'

Tags: flutter, dart

How to initialize an Int64 number in dart

I want this number to be an Int64 number.

```dart
Int64 secs = Int64(5);
```

But I get this warning

```
A value of type 'int' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Int64'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to
```

Comment: are you using any package for it?

Comment: I use gRPC basicaly I am doing test but one value has this type. So I need to provide it as (Int64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [`BigInt`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/BigInt-class.html) from dart core.

Also `Int64` from  [fixnum](https://pub.dev/documentation/fixnum/latest/fixnum/Int64-class.html).

```dart
 Int64 secs = Int64(5);
```

Comment: Thanks. I need to wait 3m for your ansear. I notice the generated gRPC files also use the fixnum package.

Answer (score 0):

You can use toInt().

Example

int result = response.result.toInt();